# Set one new origin for a group

Tags: modeling, groups

I have a group of objects and I need to set a new origin to the corner of the group. Is this possible?

I have tried to set the cursor in edit mode to one of the objects in the group and then in object mode move the origin to that cursor and then shift G Group to select all the other objects in the group.

I want to move the group to a new location in the scene. I set the cursor at the new loacation and then I select Selection to cursor, but then all the objects own origins in the group move to that point. I just want one origin for the group and be able to set the location of the origin where I want.

Comment: Parent the objects in the group to an empty. Moving the empty will move all of the objects along with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent the objects in the group to an empty. Moving the empty will move all of the objects along with it.

Comment: Hi, sorry I am new to blender, could you elaborate on this a bit more? I don't completely understand what you mean by your first sentence. What is "an empty"? Could you maybe provide a screenshot or some other sort of help on this?